# No reverseMatch error in password reset in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls, django-email

I have seen `several posts` and tried all the solutions suggested for fixing this issue. but I still have the following error. I am using `Django 1.6`.

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/Mw/3q6-5e4aba3a21e3b697aca2/
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/reset/Mw/3q6-5e4aba3a21e3b697aca2/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have tried two different `URLconfs`, both did not help. Here is what I tried.

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


# urlpatterns = patterns('',
#                        url(r'^login/$',
#                            auth_views.login,
#                            {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
#                            name='auth_login'),
#                        url(r'^logout/$',
#                            auth_views.logout,
#                            {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'},
#                            name='auth_logout'),
#                        url(r'^password/change/$',
#                            auth_views.password_change,
#                            {'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done')},
#                            name='auth_password_change'),
#                        url(r'^password/change/done/$',
#                            auth_views.password_change_done,
#                            name='auth_password_change_done'),
#                        url(r'^password/reset/$',
#                            auth_views.password_reset,
#                            {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done')},
#                            name='auth_password_reset'),
#                        url(r'^password/reset/confirm/$', 
#              'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
#              name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
# #                        url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
# #                            auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
# #                            name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
#                        url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
#                            auth_views.password_reset_complete,
#                            {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_complete')},
#                            name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
#                        url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
#                            auth_views.password_reset_done,
#                            name='auth_password_reset_done'),
# )
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^password/change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    name='auth_password_change'),
url(r'^password/change/done/$',
    auth_views.password_change_done,
    name='password_change_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/$',
    auth_views.password_reset,
    name='auth_password_reset'),
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
    name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
    name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_done,
    name='password_reset_done'),
                       )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking for a url with the name `password_reset_complete`, but your URLconf contains a view called `AUTH_password_reset_complete`.  Remove the `auth_` and it should work.